# Make option selected by default using chosen and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-chosen

Im not sure why is it that the option is not selected by default, the values are hard coded and I explicitly added 'selected' attribute on option tag but its not working. I also tried `selected="selected"` but still its not working.

in View:

```
<div class="controls">
            <select chosen="" data-ng-model="assignments"  multiple="" 
                    class="span chzn-select" style="width: 150px">
                <option value="Police">Police</option>
                <option selected value="Reporter">Reporter</option>
                <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: did you try with `ng-selected="true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you didn't have the multiple attribute. In order to get this wto work with a multuple select, you need to set it up using ng-options and then store an array of what should be selected. See this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/btqLg76v/1/

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectOptions = ['Police','Reporter','Developer'];
  $scope.assignments = [$scope.selectOptions[0],$scope.selectOptions[2]];
  console.log($scope.assignments);
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <select ng-model="assignments" ng-options="selectOptions for selectOptions in selectOptions" multiple>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *"you need to set it up using ng-options"*. Well, I have to go ahead and say: of course it's always good to use `ngOptions` directive, however he can do that way also if he wants.

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, I think its really close, was able to use it in my first implementation. But how about if it involves asynchronous operation like requesting from an api using `http.get` and in  `then` i will set the selected options `$scope.assignments = //whatever the request returns`.